# What do you call tourists who visit "extreme" holiday destinations?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

I'm speaking about tourists who choose to spend their vacations (holidays) in places that push their limits to the extreme; such as the Antarctic, Mount Everest, pluvial forests, jungles, etc.

They're not your average tourist who looks forward to a relaxing week sitting on the beach, and soaking up the sun. These people are seeking ‘danger’ and thrills.

I've come up with **excursionist**. Although [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/excursionist) didn't provide any definition, it lists several sentence examples, sadly, none of them seem to fit.

> ‘A good many of the excursionists were conveyed to the head of the lake by the steam-yacht ‘Swift,’ which made its initial journey for the season on that day.’

- What are these tourists normally called?

Idioms, and slang are also welcomed, but please say which region the latter is from.

Comment: How about  **thrill-seekerz** or **adreno-tourists** or **Xcursionistas** :)

Comment: _Excursionist_ could fit, even if it is not specific for people doing that activity while in vacation. You could say _extreme excursionist_, if you want to make clear you are talking of people going to _peculiar_ places. The NOAD doesn't give a definition of _excursionist_ too, but the version on macOS Sierra points you to _excursion_, which has the following definition: "a short journey or trip, especially one engaged in as a leisure activity: _an excursion to Mount Etna_ | figurative: _an excursion into theology_."

Comment: @TRomano I need this word for a student's English essay I am correcting, the word *tourist* is being overused. I was wondering if a term had been coined. If it hasn't that already is an answer.

Comment: Maybe travel agents have a word for them, or they have a word for themselves, but if a single term exists, it's not in general circulation.

Comment: Interesting question. One of my best friends (quite the adventurist himself) met his wife when by chance he overheard a woman at a party saying, "Heck, yes, I'd climb Mount Everest on my vacation!" _Birds of a feather..._

Comment: @J.R. I have a feeling that a standard term hasn't been found for these type of adventure-backpackers. And yet, extreme tourism is enjoying a bit of a boom even in the part of Italy where I live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The people would be "adventure tourists" or "adventure travelers".  The kind of tourism they engage in is called [Adventure Travel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_travel)

"a type of tourism, involving exploration or travel with perceived (and possibly actual) risk, and potentially requiring specialized skills and physical exertion."

Comment: Since the OP is asking for the term to use for people, I guess it should be _adventure traveller_.

Answer (score 1):

Since the meaning of *excursion* is *short journey or trip, especially one engaged in as a leisure activity*, and one of the meanings of *extreme* is *denoting or relating to a sport performed in a hazardous environment and involving great physical risk, such as parachuting or whitewater rafting*, I would use *extreme excursionist*.

Answer (score 1):

I Googled *[**thrill-seeking travellers**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=thrill-seeking+travellers)* and found a decent number of American and British English citations.

> - 5 Adrenaline Adventures for **Thrill-Seeking Travelers**.
> - **Thrill-seekers** are the *hard-core bunch of travellers*. The more adrenalin-filled physical activities you can pack into your travels, the better. You're not afraid to ...
> - Living on the EDGE: **Thrill-seeking travellers** make a living risking their LIVES [source](http://www.express.co.uk/travel/activity/704269/Thrill-seeking-travellers-make-a-living-risking-their-lives)

This [website](http://www.amadeus.com/nablog/2013/04/4-ways-to-attract-and-retain-thrill-seeking-travelers/travel-2) also uses the term **daredevil travelers**

> - Planning your thrill-seeking – or **daredevil** – **traveler’s** next getaway doesn’t have to be a white-knuckle experience for you – if you know the ropes going in.

Comment: Now I wonder to upvote your answer or your question :)

Comment: For short, in the right context, the essayist could use *thrill seekers* and *daredevils*.